# Python Search and Replace Using a List for Search

Tags: python, regex, string, list, replace

I have several lines of a file that I'm looping through and have stored as strings and I'm looking to perform a simple search and replace in each line using either the method built into python strings `str.replace()` or using regular expressions `re.sub()` but using a list as argument for the old substring. I know the format usually goes as follows:

`string.replace('oldsubstring','newsubstring')`

However, if I have a list of strings: `['word1', 'word2', 'word3']`, is it possible to use this as the `oldsubstring` argument so that if *any* of the elements in the list are found in `string`, that element is replaced with `newsubstring`. I know this is possible using a double nested for loop that loops through all of my lines and my list of strings, but I'm looking for a more efficient algorithm to accomplish this.

**Follow Up Question:**

Another problem I have found is that there are times where my list of strings will look like:

`['word1', 'word1_suffix', 'word2', 'word3']` NOTE: Order of these elements is not guaranteed to be the same each run.

When using the double nested for loop method, if `word1_suffix` appears in the current line I'm looking at, and I then loop through my list of strings, if `word1` happens to appear in my list of strings first, the replacement will be `newsubstring_suffix` rather than replacing the entire substring: `word1_suffix` with `newsubstring`.

NOTE: I know that using a regular expression I can ensure that `word1_suffix` is it's own full word surrounded by spaces, but that are times where I do want a part of my line that follows the format: `word1_miscellaneous` to be replaced as `newsubstring_miscellaneous` so that method will not entirely solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With `re.sub` you can use the greedy character of regex to make sure `word1_suffix` isn't replaced by `newsubstring_suffix`:

```
your_string = "hello word1_suffix world word3"

word_list = ['word1', 'word1_suffix', 'word2', 'word3']
word_set = set(word_list)

# pattern to match all 'words' (succession of letters, digits and _):
word_pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
print(re.sub(word_pattern, lambda x: "newsubstring" if x.group() in word_set else x.group(), your_string))
```

The lambda function check if the matched group is in `word_set` and replace it with `newsubstring`.

Output:

```
hello newsubstring world newsubstring
```